# Check whether user can delete a given post

Tags: capabilities, user-roles

I have run into this problem where the following piece of code always returns true for any `post ID` supplied to it.

`current_user_can('delete_posts', $post_id);`

Normally, the above code should return false when the user is not the author of the post or does not have the capability to delete others post. However, it still returns true for any post ID.

The user has been assigned a custom role, as defined below.

```
$standard_role_capabilities = array ('read'                 => true,
                                    'delete_posts'              => true,
                                    'edit_posts'                => true,
                                    'delete_published_posts'    => true,
                                    'publish_posts'             => true,
                                    'edit_published_posts'      => true,
                                    'comment'                   => true
                            );

add_role('standard', 'Standard', $standard_role_capabilities);
```

Any reasons for this not working?

Comment: You should accept your answer. It is funny, because I thought to look at whether it should be plural or not, because it seemed like it should be, and then I just decided that it must be right...

Comment: @Jake I'd have to wait for 24hrs before I can accept my answer. Will do once 24hrs go by.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hours of fighting to get this to work, it was just a matter of changing `delete_posts` to `delete_post`.

So, in it's entirety this would be:

`current_user_can('delete_posts', $post_id);`

to

`current_user_can('delete_post', $post_id);`

`current_user_can` does accept a second parameter. Though it's weird that the function declaration in `capabilities.php` does not define a second parameter as pointed out by @amit. May be someone can clarify why it is so.

Comment: The reason that only the first parameter is documented is because the value of any other parameter(s) varies based on the capability being checked. As you can see, the other parameters provide context for the capability. For `'delete_post'` the second parameter is the ID of the post. For other capabilities, it might be something different, or not used at all (as with `'delete_posts'`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if user can delete posts of other authors, you need to use proper capability - `delete_others_posts`.

Comment: Well, thx for the suggestion. However, this won't work. I need to check whether a particular post could be deleted by the current user. Not whether the user can delete others posts.

Comment: This seems like your answer. You have given your user the abilty to delete all posts. If you want to give them the ability to only delete their own posts, you need to define that in their capabilities. You haven't done that. So define "delete_others_posts" => false in their capabilities, and then you can check the way you are currently and it will work.

Comment: @Jake The user has only been given the capability to delete their own posts. User does not have the capability to `delete_others_posts`. BTW, got this working. Please see the answer I added.

Comment: I see, the default is off, of course. I wasn't thinking right. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

> ### EDIT -
>
> There's another function [author_can()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/author_can) Which'll accept post ID.

`current_user_can()` function accepts only [one parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can#Parameters), we can not pass the post id to it.

> ### Parameters -
>
> ```
> $capability
> (string) (required) capability
> Default: None
> ```

### Example -

**May be this is not the best way to achieve what you're looking for -** 
 I guess in the below code, the if block will only get executed when current user is `author` of that post and has capability - `delete_posts`

```
<?php

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $author = get_the_author_meta('ID');

    if ( current_user_can('delete_posts') && ( $current_user->ID == $author ) ) {
        //  when current user is author with `delete_posts` capability
    }

?>
```

### Update -

> Allow user to delete his own posts but disallow deletion of others post.
>   If deletion is based on author of post then an administrator will not be able to delete the post even though the administrator has the privileges

Change the if statement to something like this -

```
    if ( current_user_can('activate_plugins') || ( $current_user->ID == $author ) ) 
    {
        //  when current user is author or admin
    }
```

Comment: That's what I'd thought. However, looking at the `edit_posts` example on the Codex page (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) for `current_user_can` I'd say it could accept the post ID as well.

Comment: Ok, see my edit, I think you're looking for `author_can()` function.

Comment: `author_can` will not work. It checks whether the author of the post has a particular capability. Rather here I am looking whether a particular user can delete a given post. Two different things going in there. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: If current user has cap to `delete_posts` then he can delete any post. So you want to prevent that user from deleting other users post ?

Comment: Yep! Exactly. Allow user to delete his own posts but disallow deletion of others post. This should be based on user's capability. Not on whether the user is the author of the post. If deletion is based on author of post then an administrator will not be able to delete the post even though the administrator has the privileges.

Comment: See the update, that if statement comes true if current user is admin or author of current post

Comment: @John See [wp-includes/capabilities.php#L1194](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L1194), There's no second parameter.

Comment: Please see my answer. Got this working! Thx for the help, btw.